# Store QR scanned URLs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, plugins, qr-code

I'm using [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) plugin for Cordova to scan QR codes. The QR scanner is triggered when a "scan QR code" button is clicked inside the app. The barcode scanner plugin works great. Now, I'm trying to store those values scanned as variables in Javascript.
The plugin itself uses this function:

```
function startScan() {
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
function (results){
    var s = "Result: " + result.text + "<br/>" +
    "Format: " + result.format + "<br />" +
    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled;
    resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
},
function (error) {
    alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
}
)
```

Where `resultDiv` is a global variable and is initailized as follows:

```
document.querySelector("#startScan").addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
```

As I mentioned the scanning works fine, but my results page is blank(except for the header) after testing. The results page is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagethree"  style="text-transform:none">
        <div align="center">
            <div id="results">
            <h1>Report</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would you represent QR codes(URLs) in html where the there is no limit of QR codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The param results of your inner function never get used in your sample.

```
function startScan() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (results){
            var s = "Result: " + results.text + "<br/>" +
            "Format: " + results.format + "<br />" +
            "Cancelled: " + results.cancelled;
            resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
        },

        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        })};
```

Comment: How would I use 'results' here? I'm a little lost as to how.

Comment: you were using var result and not results as declared as param in your inner function -> _function(results) {_